# how to select attributes to show (name, height,weight ) swapi.co

Tags: javascript, ajax

shows all the attributes, I need only name weight growth, eye color, skin color and gender

```js
url = "https://swapi.co/api/people";
 
function heroes () {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          console.log(data); // see object

    }
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; //  write info

};
    xhr.open("get", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with an example output of the array data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're started by showing the request and parsing into a JSON object. That's a good start!

Now, you need to iterate each result (you can use a for loop) and render the property.

I've built an example, here's the code:

#### Html:

```
<div id="output">
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
var url = "https://swapi.co/api/people";

function heroes() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      var tableContent = '<table>'
      tableContent += "<thead><tr>";
      tableContent += "<td>Name</td>";
      tableContent += "<td>Height</td>";
      tableContent += "<td>Mass</td>";
      tableContent += "<td>Eye Color</td>";
      tableContent += "<td>Skin Color</td>";
      tableContent += "<td>Gender</td>";
      tableContent += "</tr></thead>";
      for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
        var person = data.results[i];
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + person.name + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + person.height + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + person.mass + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + person.eye_color + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + person.skin_color + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + person.gender + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      }
      tableContent += "</table>"

      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = tableContent; // write table

    }
    // document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; //  write info
  };
  xhr.open("get", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}

heroes();
```

Here's a pen, if you want to [see it live](https://codepen.io/Rechousa/full/YeopwJ/).